# Typescript global enums?

Tags: typescript

I have the following legacy javascript:

```
var RED = "red";
var GREEN = "green";
var BLUE = "blue";

function foo(color) {
   // color MUST be RED, GREEN, or BLUE
}

// eg...
foo(RED);
```

is there a way to encode this in a `.d.ts` file?

i cannot change the javascript.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that `RED`, `GREEN` and `BLUE` are treated as if their values won't change.

First, you can explicitly state the type of each - each of which have a *string literal type*:

```
declare var RED: "red";
declare var GREEN: "green";
declare var BLUE: "blue";
```

> Note: you might even want to just declare these as `const` declarations instead.

Then you can create a `Color` type based on these:

```
type Color = typeof RED
           | typeof GREEN
           | typeof BLUE;
```

or alternatively

```
type Color = "red"
           | "green"
           | "blue";
```

Finally, whenever you accept only one of those few values, use the `Color` type:

```
declare function foo(color: Color): any;
```

Comment: yeah, but I'd expect it to suggest RED|GREEN|BLUE instead of the string values.